# Angular APP_INITIALIZER provider getting one injected service as undefined but others are injected just fine

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular6, angular7, angular8

Basically I have a provider running on app initialization. One service is being injected fine no problem, but the other is returning undefined. I tried putting a console.log statement on both of their constructors and they are both running before my provider so I have NO idea why only one of them is undefined when I try to use it.

All Help is appreciated.

Here's my code. If you need more let me know.

AppModule

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    AppProvider, 
    // ...
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (provider: AppProvider) => () => provider.load(),
      deps: [AppProvider],
      multi: true
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

AppProvider

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AppProvider {
  constructor(
              // ...
              private participantService: ParticipantService,
              private dstService: DSTService) {
  }
  load() {
    //...
    console.log(participantService); // prints undefined
    console.log(dstService); // prints the service
    // ...
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

ParticipantService

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ParticipantService {
  // ...
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              // ...
              private router: Router){
  }
  // ...
}
```

DSTService

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DSTService{
  // ...
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private participantService: ParticipantService,
              // ...
              private router: Router){
  }
  // ...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try sth like this : `{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => inject(AppProvider).load(),
        multi: true
    }`

Comment: `Error: inject() must be called from an injection context`

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Facing the same issue

Comment: I added an empty service to the list that does nothing and is loaded first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well sorry to mislead you. `inject` function only injects tokens it seems. So we can use `INJECTOR` token to inject a service injector into our token. So it became sth like this:

```
import { SOME_TOKEN } from "./token";
import { NgModule, inject, INJECTOR } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    HelloService,
    {
      provide: SOME_TOKEN,
      useFactory: () => {
        return inject(INJECTOR)
          .get(HelloService)
          .getHello();
      }
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jr7rvn) example.

Comment: this helps my scenario, however, wondering why APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER not a fit here

Comment: @javapedia.net good catch. The reason is I didn't think of it at the posting time. But, since `APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER` provides a callback that runs for every bootstrapped component. The callback is called after the bootstrapping process. So it still may not fit.